# External Python Dependencies in Dataflow Pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Can python dependencies be loaded into a Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline?

I would like to use [gensim's phrase modeler](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html) which reads data line by line to automatically detect common phrases/bigrams (two words that frequently appear next to each other).

So the first run through of the pipeline would be passing each sentence to this phrase modeler.

The second pass through the pipeline would then take the same phrase modeler and apply this phrase modeler to each sentence to identify the phrases that should be modeled together. Example:

- If `machine` and `learning` frequently appear next to each other in the corpus, they would be transformed to a single word `machine_learning` instead.

Would this be possible to accomplish within Dataflow?

Can a build/requirements file be passed forcing `pip install gensim` on the worker machines?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check out this page for managing dependencies in your pipeline:

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies

example: For packages on PyPI, you can use requirement file by adding the following command line option:

--requirements_file requirements.txt